# apache2 dbd failed to initialise error AH02654 using postgresql on debian jessie

Tags: apache-2.4, postgresql, debian-jessie

I'm currently trying to set up an apache server with mirrorbrain on debian jessie, mirrorbrain uses dbd to connect to the database. Unofrtunately I get the following in the error log

[Sun Oct 18 13:47:47.801830 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 7619:tid 140365218666240] (20014)Internal error: AH00633: failed to initialise

in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dbd.conf I have (I replaced my actual password with <censored> when posting here)

```
<IfModule mod_dbd.c>
    DBDriver pgsql
    DBDParams 'host=127.0.0.1 user=mirrorbrain password=<censored> dbname=mirrorbrain connect_timeout=15'
</IfModule>
```

any idea how to track down what the problem is? I can successfully connect to the db using the psql command line client with the same settings that dbd is configured to use. I have libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql installed.

Answers to questions in comments:

Yes I did use a2enmod dbd to enable dbd

The debian apache2.conf contains 
    # Include module configuration:
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Which loads the modules and their configuration including the dbd.conf which I created (I know it is being loaded because the error changed when I created it).

Comment: did you a2enmod dbd? And which file includes dbd.conf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it seems the answer in my case was "look at the global error.log". The useless error message was in both the vhost specific error log and the global error log but the useful error message was only in the global error.log

```
[Sun Oct 18 13:24:07.617235 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 4571:tid 140683085744000] (20014)Internal error: AH00632: failed to prepare SQL statements: ERROR:  relation "pfx2asn" does not exist\nLINE 1: ...EPARE asn_dbd_1 (varchar) AS SELECT pfx, asn FROM pfx2asn WH...\n                                                             ^\n
[Sun Oct 18 13:24:07.617339 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 4571:tid 140683085744000] (20014)Internal error: AH00633: failed to initialise
[Sun Oct 18 13:24:07.617352 2015] [dbd:crit] [pid 4571:tid 140683085744000] (20014)Internal error: AH00636: child init failed!
```